# Laravel custom storage:link

Tags: laravel, image, storage

I have a folder in the: -> storage/app/ and I need to make a symbolic link.

Since the `php artisan storage:link` links -> storage/app/public with -> public/storage.

What would be the best aproach to create a symbolic link for a folder that is not in the storage/app/public?

Or I always need to save images in the storage/app/public?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make symlinks manually aswell. You could use midnight commander or linux command for that. You can open midnight commander with the command `mc`, and you can make symlink with the linux command `ln` (see: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-symbolic-links-in-linux-using-the-ln-command/)

If you need further help let me know

Comment: Mátyás Grőger how could be that same thing? if you create it using ln -s wont work, but php artisan storage:link will work. Somehow it is different

Comment: it is not the same command, but the effect is similar